# Where can I see the log statements of a task in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, perl, task-scheduler

I created a task in task scheduler which essentially runs a perl script. I have some print/log statements in the script. Where can I see these log statements?

Answer (score 0):

Output from a script run in task scheduler goes to stdout as normal, which is lost at the end of the script running.

If you want to capture the output from a task, either write the output to a log file instead of stdout, or have a redirect in your task command line:

```
perl mytask.pl >> c:\perltasklogfile.txt
```

If you want any errors captured in the same file, use:

```
perl mytask.pl >> c:\perltasklogfile.txt 2>&1
```